# Schwartz Space on a Manifold

Tags: manifolds

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Schwartz space is an incredibly nice space of functions, and in many ways is more natural than $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$.  On a manifold $M$, it of course still makes sense to talk about $C_c^\infty(M)$, but what about $\mathcal{S}(M)$, the Schwartz space on $M$?  Is there a way we can define this on a general smooth manifold $M$?

Comment: It probably makes sense for a manifold which is flat outside of a compact set.

Comment: You should probably post a link to MO, in case someone stops by here later

Comment: @YemonChoi Good idea.  I have asked this question on MO as well:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80094/the-schwartz-space-on-a-manifold